# Problem with config env for datasource in loopback 3

Tags: node.js, api, loopbackjs

I am using loopback to develop API, and having problem with config by env in lb3, i have **datasources.json** file as below

```
{
  "SSOSystem": {
    "host": "x.y.z.o",
    "port": 27017,
    "url": "mongodb://SSO-System-mongo:U5KckMwrWs9EGyAh@x.y.z.o/SSO-System",
    "database": "SSO-System",
    "password": "U5KckMwrWs9EGyAh",
    "name": "SSOSystem",
    "connector": "mongodb",
    "user": "SSO-System-mongo"
  }
}
```

and **datasources.local.js** as below

```
module.exports = {
  SSOSytem: {
    connector: 'mongodb',
    hostname: process.env.SSO_DB_HOST || 'localhost',
    port: process.env.SSO_DB_PORT || 27017,
    user: process.env.SSO_DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.SSO_DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.SSO_DB_NAME,
    url: `mongodb://${process.env.SSO_DB_USERNAME}:${process.env.SSO_DB_PASSWORD}@${process.env.SSO_DB_HOST}/${process.env.SSO_DB_NAME}`
  }
}
```

but when I run my app with env **local**
`NODE_ENV=local node .`
loopback only loads datasources from datasources.json file, did I do something wrong in datasources config? Does anyone have same problem with me?

Many thanks,

Comment: According to the [docs](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Environment-specific-configuration.html#data-source-configuration) it should work. I remember I had an issue when I was using `local` environment - `local` is always taken after the default config and it will be loaded even if you don't specify any environment. So first the default, then `xxx.local.js`, then `xxx.env.js` - if specified. Maybe try to use `develop` env?

Comment: Thanks @akkonrad, I had change to develop and development, it still load config from datasources.json instead of datasources.developement.js. Env I put in .env file ```SSO_DB_NAME=SSO-System
SSO_DB_HOST=localhost
SSO_DB_PORT=27017
SSO_DB_USERNAME=dev
SSO_DB_PASSWORD=fuck0ff
NODE_ENV=developement``` and use ```require('dotenv').config();``` load env from .env file

Comment: Sorry, this is my typo mistake not problem of loopback SSOSystem in datasources.json and SSOSytem in file datasources.local.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this is my typo mistake not problem of loopback SSOSystem in datasources.json and SSOSytem in file datasources.local.js